# Spring STOMP Websockets: failed to open session

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, servlets, stomp

I'm using Google appengine standard enviornment with Spring and I'm trying to get STOMP to work on a basic website. I have seen many with the same error as me but none of the solutions I've tried has worked so far.

This is the error I get:

> org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException:
>   Failed to open session; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Async support must be enabled on a
>   servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This
>   is   done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations
>   in   web.xml. Also you must use a Servlet 3.0+ container

This is my ServletInitializer:

```
@EnableAsync
@EnableWebMvc
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            new DispatcherServlet(), "/");
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registration;
  }
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

}
```

This is my Websocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

And this is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.google.appengine.demos</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-appengine-standard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springboot-appengine-standard</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>



    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring.boot.version>1.5.8.RELEASE</spring.boot.version> <!-- DO NOT UPDATE w/o MANUAL TESTING -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>sockjs-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>stomp-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Exclude any jul-to-slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Include Servlet API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- [START cloudplugin] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- [END cloudplugin] -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api</exclude>
                        <exclude>com.google.guava:guava</exclude> <!-- avoid android version -->
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

This is my appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
Copyright 2017 Google Inc.
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
        <property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
    </system-properties>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: which runtime are you using? Java 7 or Java 8? This is defined in appengine-web.xml file

Comment: I am using java 8 @MichaelMeyer

Comment: can you please post your appengine-web.xml file?

Comment: I edited the post with it! @MichaelMeyer

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: @emirc It seems like Google App Engine standard enviorment blocks all socket connections by default so my solution was to move everything to the compute engine instead.